# SharePoint 2007-2010 Filter views problems with AND & OR

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-designer

Heres my problem :

Whenever i try to create a view of a list with different conditions (more than 4)

I'm not sure if i just dont get it here are my conditions, they are on a calendar view
my calendar has a custom column named "State of approbation" which can have those values : "Done", "Cancelled", "Approved", "In approbation". I have another custom column which i want to filter it is : "Upcoming date" it is a "Yes/No" type.

Heres what i want to show :

I dont want to show events that are Done.

I dont want to show canceled events more than 14 days.

I dont want to show upcoming date events since the date is not confirmed.

---

I thought of the following :

Upcoming date = No

AND

State of approbation != Done

AND

State of approbation = Canceled

AND

Modified >= [TODAY]-14

which is not working. I have been looking for a workaround and tought of this one too :

Upcoming date = No

AND

State of approbation != Done

OR

State of approbation = Canceled

AND

Modified >= [TODAY]-14

AND

Upcoming date = No

It is not working either.

I would gladly welcome some help.

-Gus

Comment: "which is not working." - How is it not working - syntax error or showing the wrong info?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a yes/no field the values are not yes and no like you are using.  Switch that field to a choice column and only specify yes or no as options then your filter will work.